# Django rest api to list values ManytoMany field

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

Im have two models, Manager and Template, one Template has n Managers, 
I want with the template id to get all the managers of the same

I tried to make an api that takes the url template id, and filters the relationship table but it returns me empty

This my models

```py
class Template(TimestampedModel, permissions.TemplatesPermission):
    title = models.CharField(
        max_length=1000,
        db_column='titulo',
        verbose_name='título',
        db_index=True,
    )
    description = models.TextField(
        db_column='descricao',
        verbose_name='descrição',
    )
    active = models.BooleanField(
        default=True,
    )
    managers = models.ManyToManyField(
        Manager,
        through='TemplateManager',
    )
    validity_date = models.DateTimeField(
        db_column='data_vigencia',
        verbose_name='data de vigência',
    )

    class Meta:
        db_table = 'declaracoes_template'
        verbose_name = 'Template'
        verbose_name_plural = 'Templates'

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

```py
class Manager(TimestampedModel):
    user = models.ForeignKey(
        settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL,
        models.CASCADE,
        verbose_name='usuário',
    )
    file = models.CharField(
        max_length=1000,
        db_column='assinatura',
        verbose_name='assinatura do gestor',
    )
    position = models.ForeignKey(
        Position,
        models.PROTECT,
        db_column='cargo',
        verbose_name='cargo',
    )

    class Meta:
        db_table = 'declaracoes_gestor'
        verbose_name = 'Gestores'
        verbose_name_plural = 'Gestores'

    def __str__(self):
        return self.user
```

```py
class TemplateManager(TimestampedModel):
    manager = models.ForeignKey(
        Manager,
        on_delete=models.PROTECT,
        db_column='gestor_id',
    )
    template = models.ForeignKey(
        Template,
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        db_column='template_id',
    )
```

This my view

```py
class TemplateManagerView(APIView):
    pagination_class = BasePagination

    def get(self, request, id):
        template = get_object_or_404(models.Template.objects.all(), id=id)

        managers = (models.TemplateManager.objects
            .filter(template=template)
            .all())
        serializer = serializers.ManagerSerializer(managers, many=True)
        return Response(serializer.data)
```

and my serializers

```py
class ManagerSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    position = PositionSerializer()
    user = serializers.CharField(source='user.first_name')

    class Meta:
        model = models.Manager
        fields = ['id', 'user', 'file', 'position']


class ManagerTemplateSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    manager = ManagerSerializer(many=True)
    template = TemplateSerializer(many=True)

    class Meta:
        fields = ['manager', 'template']
        model = models.Template
```

my url something like /id/managers

Comment: Have you read this page: https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/relations/ ?

Comment: thanks for answer, I read but i couldn't, I'm a beginner and this is the first model I do n to n

Comment: have you tried using a nested serializer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you don't need to pass a query to `get_object_or_404`. This will work just fine:

```
get_object_or_404(models.Template, id=id)
```

Also, you are passing the wrong queryset:

```
managers = (models.TemplateManager.objects
        .filter(template=template)
        .all())
```

This can be changed to this:

```
models.TemplateManager.objects
        .filter(template=template)
```

Which is a queryset from `TemplateManager` model while you're using the serializer for 
`ManagerSerializer` serializer for `Manager` model.

Now, to fix this:

1 - change model in `ManagerTemplateSerializer` to `TemplateManager` instead of `Template`.

2 - change `serializer = serializers.ManagerSerializer(managers, many=True)` to `serializer = serializers.ManagerTemplateSerializer(managers, many=True)`